# cannot find -lpthread but found in /usr/lib as well as /usr/local/lib and path set in LD_LBRARY_PATH

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, pthreads, linker-errors

I'm facing a weird situation where in, I have my libpthread.so library present in /usr/lib and env variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is also set to the same path. Even then I get the error  *cannot find -lpthread*. My exact linker statement is

```
  /usr/bin/ld dummyfuncUT.o Handler.o  -L ../../../lib/ -L /usr/lib -lpthread -lgmock -L /usr/local/gmock-1.6.0/lib -r -O1 -o ../HandlerUT.o
```

can anybody please help me through. I'm using RHEL6 with g++4.4.4.